# Forward and back buttons for navigating through images

Tags: navigation, back-button

I have a window with forward and back buttons in the navigation area above the image view.

The left one is forward and the right one is back.

When the view is first opened, it display the newest image.

My dilemma:

It feels more natural to click on the arrow on the right to continue to the next image, but it feels weird to click the forward button to go back in time. It's the opposite of the way browsers work.

Should I switch it around?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would switch it around. Just like the way that we turn a page in a book, with each click on the right side we expect to go forward in the progression. Same with reading words, we go left to right and progress forward that way.

Comment: this is with the caveat of course that some languages (and thus books in those languages) are read right to left. Even still, I believe the convention is solid enough that for 99% of cases left to right is the best answer.

Comment: Yes that's true that some languages and cultures read from right to left. I guess in the end it is all about knowing the audience you are trying to hit. I have yet to please everyone that uses my site ;).